# Fails to read certfile/keyfile when run as SYSTEMD

Tags: ssl, python, certificate, systemd, mqtt

EDIT:

I wrote a python script that starts mosquitto client with TLS options ON. All worked fine when I run it from command line (w/o sudo). Now it broke after re-installing some packages.

However, I needed the script to start on system boot, so I created a SYSTEMD service to run as a daemon. Based on the service status report, I infer that the `cert` or `key` files are not available, so the daemon exists with error. The files are in the same directory as the .py script. Any ideas what the problem could be?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/FONA_PROJECT $ sudo systemctl status fonagps.service 
● fonagps.service - Vechicle Tracking System
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fonagps.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-03-19 22:17:59 UTC; 3s ago
Process: 1526 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/FONA_PROJECT/iot_sub.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 1526 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 19 22:17:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Vechicle Tracking System.
Mar 19 22:17:59 raspberrypi python[1526]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 19 22:17:59 raspberrypi python[1526]:   File "/home/pi/FONA_PROJECT/iot_sub.py", line 129, in <module>
Mar 19 22:17:59 raspberrypi python[1526]:     client.tls_set(ca_certs=ca_certs, certfile=certfile, keyfile=keyfile, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)
Mar 19 22:17:59 raspberrypi python[1526]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 694, in tls_set
Mar 19 22:17:59 raspberrypi python[1526]:     context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
Mar 19 22:17:59 raspberrypi python[1526]: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Mar 19 22:17:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: fonagps.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 19 22:17:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: fonagps.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 19 22:17:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: fonagps.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: You didn't supply the correct path to your certificates.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yep, forgot the "user" in the path.